# Why cache needs to be enabled/disabled in bootloader?

Tags: bootloader

I have some doubts about ARM bootloader.

1. Is cache enabled or disabled in bootloader?
2. Why cache needs to be enabled/disabled in bootloader? What will happen?
3. Who will manage cache in bootloader ? On what basis cache entry will be made ?

Comment: you can refer below thread which might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262014/arm-bootloader-disable-mmu-and-caches

Answer (score 0):

1. Is cache enabled or disabled in bootloader?
   It all depends on the architecture of the boot-loader. But in general, enabling cache (instruction cache in specific) allows 'fast' execution. So, if boot-loader needs to perform certain task repeatedly, e.g. deciphering a binary etc, then 'fast' execution would help.
2. Why cache needs to be enabled/disabled in bootloader? What will happen?
   First part of this question is already answered above.
   If cache is disabled, of-course boot-loader will behave like a normal firmware / bare-metal code.
   But if enabled, then boot-loader needs to provide correct mapping table to MMU, with all precautions such as for SFR region none of the caching should be enabled and so on.
3. Who will manage cache in bootloader ? On what basis cache entry will be made  ?
   Cache is anyways managed by MMU. But as mentioned above, mapping needs to be provided by boot-loader or any executing entity to MMU so that depending on address-range, cache is enabled or disabled. ARM provides multiple levels of granularity for memory mapping, so as per requirements memory sections can be defined and behavior of cache can be finely controlled.